# background.js is not receiving chrome.runtime messages

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following flow in my Google Chrome extension:

popupup.html runs popup.js (works fine):

```
  <body>
    <button id="copy">Get Data</button>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

popup.js executes a basicData.js (works fine):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("copy").addEventListener("click", startHandler);
});


function startHandler() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "basicData.js"}, function() {
});
}
```

basicData.js does some calculations etc and then sends a message to the background script:

```
...
console.log("Hello world"); //prints fine
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...data});
```

background.js does not receive any message:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response,sender,sendResponse) {

  console.log("hiya")

  if (response.type==="Data complete"){
    console.log("Hello2");
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage({...response});
  }

})
```

Here is my manifest.json for reference:

```
{
    "name": "Project X",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>","http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
          "js": ["testScript.js"]
        }
      ],
      "browser_action": { 
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' wss://*.firebaseio.com;",
      "permissions": ["tabs","storage","declarativeContent", "activeTab","http://*/","https://*/","webNavigation"],
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

I copied most of this code and flow from a Google Chrome extension I made in the past which worked absolutely fine, so I am not sure why either basicData.js is not sending the message or background.js is not receiving it. All suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: 1) [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029), 2) chrome.tabs.sendMessage needs a tab id as the first parameter, for example `sender.tab.id`, however it's usually better to use `sendResponse` and a callback in basicData.js, see [examples of messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: I was looking at the popup.js log!